# How to call jQuery.sheet.SUM() method?

Tags: javascript, jquery, jquery-plugins

How can I call [jQuery.sheet](http://visop-dev.com/Project+jQuery.sheet) SUM method from my custom method? I've experimented with `PI()`, to start:

```
$.sheet.instance[0].PI();
```

But I am sure I am wrong.

Actually I want to call `SUM` method, but I think if I can call `PI()` then I can use `SUM` in the same way.

Answer (score 1):

Since jQuery.sheet v2.0.0 it is jFN.PI() (or jQuery.sheet.fn.PI()).  But please note, most of the methods since v2.0.0 are looking for "this" being the owner or cell calling the function.